# Дата с leading zero

Tags: java, дата

Всем привет. Надо с помощью метода toString() вывести дату в формате дд/мм/гггг. Данные типа int вбиваются в конструктор и на их основании надо вывести дату. Проблема в том что если дата третье марта 2020, то нужно чтобы выходило 03/03/2020, а не 3/3/2020.

```
public String toString() {
        if (getDay() < 10 & getMonth() < 10) {
            return String.format("0%d", getDay()) + "/" + String.format("0%d", getMonth()) + "/" + String.format("%d", getYear());
        } else if (getDay() < 10 & getMonth() > 9) {
            return String.format("0%d", getDay()) + "/" + String.format("%d", getMonth()) + "/" + String.format("%d", getYear());
        } else if (getDay() > 9 || getMonth() < 10) {
            return String.format("0%d", getDay()) + "/" + String.format("0%d", getMonth()) + "/" + String.format("%d", getYear());
        } else return "Дата введена некоректно";
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://ideone.com/VBD1bJ

```
String.format("%02d", 1)
String.format("%02d", 10)
String.format("%02d", 100)
```

```
String.format("%02d/%02d/%04d", getDay(), getMonth(), getYear())
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы